# PDO Function simplification

Tags: php, pdo

Here is my function.

I want to simplify this function.

Any one help me please?

```
public function showData($table,$fields,$values) 
{

        $first = true;
        $whereClause=null;
        foreach($fields as $key => $value)
        {
            if($first)
                    {
                        $whereClause .= " WHERE $value = '$values[$key]'";
                        $first = false;
               }
                else
                    {
                        $whereClause .= " AND $value = '$values[$key]'";
               }
      }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table $whereClause";
        $q = $this->conn->prepare($sql) or die("failed!");
        $q->execute();
        while ($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            $data[] = $r;
        }
        return $data;
}
foreach($ob->showData($tablenm,$field,$val) as $roleval)
{
      //Do Something
}
```

Any other way to simplify this function.

Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function query($sql, $params = NULL)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params)
    return $stmt; 
}

$data = $ob->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo = ? AND bar = ?", [$foo, $bar]);
foreach($data as $roleval)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

This function is way more simpler, way more powerful and way more flexible than yours. Put aside that yours is **essentially and irrecoverably prone to SQL injection**, just mocking a prepared statement but not using it really.

You have to understand that keywords in SQL serve for the great purpose of readability, makes whole statement readable and unambiguous, comprehensible by the every programmer in the world. And so you can tell that your initial idea to save yourself typing of SELECT or WHERE turns to be not that brilliant.

Besides, PDO supports dozens of different return formats, while you are limiting yourself with only one.

You may read further in my article [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Answer (score -1):

```
function showData($table, $fields, $values) {
  if(!(is_array($fields) && is_array($values) ) || count($fields) !== count($values))
    throw new Exception('Arguments error: "fields" and "values" must be arrays with equal number of elements.');

  foreach ($fields as $key => &$field)
    $field = '`' . str_replace('`', '``', $field) . '` = ' . $this->conn->quote($values[$key]);

  return 'SELECT * FROM `' . str_replace('`', '``', $table) . (empty($fields) ? '`' : '` WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $fields)) . ';';
}
```

test case:

```
echo showData('table`name', ['col`1', 'col\`2', 'col\\`3'], ["Tom's cat 1", "Tom's cat 2", "Tom's cat 3"]);

#output: SELECT * FROM `table``name` WHERE `col``1` = 'Tom\'s cat 1' AND `col\``2` = 'Tom\'s cat 2' AND `col\``3` = 'Tom\'s cat 3';
```

*Of course you will execute the SQL instead of returning it as test output.*